# angular 4.3 [style.box-shadow] or [style.boxShadow] not working

Tags: angular, css, dom

I've tried applying this code to a `div` and I don't see any result.

```
 [style.box-shadow]="'0px 0px 10.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)'"
```

All other **style properties** are working fine for ex.

```
  [style.border], [style.color]="textColor" etc.
```

What's the trick? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rgba()` doesn't work with that notation but hashtag work with it like `[style.box-shadow]="'0px 0px 10.5px #000'"`.

If you need `rgba()` notation, use `NgStyle` directive instead of `[style.prop]` notation.

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'box-shadow': '0px 0px 10.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)'}"></div>
```

Comment: I have used the same thing in my stylescript. But why isn't it showing up in the output ?